# Javascript doesn't work on blade laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to create a table which I can delete a row by clicking a button on it's last cell but It doesn't work. I move it to a test project (without laravel), it works, but doesn't work on blade laravel. I have tried as many ways as I can but still couldn't figure it out.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" {{asset('public/css/cart.css')}}">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("td.cart_delete").on("click", function () {
    alert("On click");
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
</script>

@extends('layouts.layout')

@section('content')       
 <section id="cart_items">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="breadcrumbs">
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li><a href="#">Trang chủ</a></li>
                    <li class="active">Giỏ hàng</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <div class="table-responsive cart_info">
                <table class="table table-condensed">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="cart_menu">
                            <td class="image">Mặt hàng</td>
                            <td class="description">Mô tả</td>
                            <td class="price">Giá</td>
                            <td class="quantity">Số lượng</td>
                            <td class="total">Thành tiền</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="cart_product">
                                <a href=""><img src="images/cart/one.png" alt=""></a>  <!-- Cái này chứa ảnh của sp -->
                            </td>
                            <td class="cart_description">
                                <h4><a href="">Tên sản phẩm</a></h4>     <!-- Tên sản phẩm -->
                                <p><a>Phan Thanh Tuyên</a></p>
                            </td>
                            <td class="cart_price">
                                <p>120.000 VNĐ</p>       <!--  Giá -->
                            </td>
                            <td class="cart_quantity"> <!--  Số lượng -->
                                <div class="cart_quantity_button">
                                    <!-- <a class="cart_quantity_up" href=""> + </a> -->
                                    <button class="add-btn">+</button>
                                    <input class="cart_quantity_input" type="text" name="quantity" value="1" autocomplete="off" size="2" id="so_luong">          <!-- Đây cần thay đổi số lượng sản phẩm mua theo csdl -->
                                    <!-- <a class="cart_quantity_down" href=""> - </a> -->
                                    <button class="minus-btn">-</button>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="cart_total">
                                <p class="cart_total_price">$59</p>
                            </td>
                            <td class="cart_delete">
                                <!-- <a class="cart_quantity_delete" href=""><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a> Đây là nút delete một sản phẩm trong giỏ hàng. Chưa biết nên để <button> hay <a>. Cái này tùy cách xử lý của ô -->
                                <button class="quantity_delete"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td class="cart_product">
                                <a href=""><img src="images/cart/two.png" alt=""></a>
                            </td>
                            <td class="cart_description">
                                <h4><a href="">Colorblock Scuba</a></h4>
                                <p>Web ID: 1089772</p>
                            </td>
                            <td class="cart_price">
                                <p>$59</p>
                            </td>
                            <td class="cart_quantity">
                                <div class="cart_quantity_button">
                                    <button class="add-btn">+</button>
                                    <input class="cart_quantity_input" type="text" name="quantity" value="1" autocomplete="off" size="2">
                                    <button class="minus-btn">-</button>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="cart_total">
                                <p class="cart_total_price">$59</p>
                            </td>
                            <td class="cart_delete">
                                <!-- <a class="cart_quantity_delete" href=""><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a> -->
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="cart_product">
                                <a href=""><img src="images/cart/three.png" alt=""></a>
                            </td>
                            <td class="cart_description">
                                <h4><a href="">Colorblock Scuba</a></h4>
                                <p>Web ID: 1089772</p>
                            </td>
                            <td class="cart_price">
                                <p>$59</p>
                            </td>
                            <td class="cart_quantity">
                                <div class="cart_quantity_button">
                                    <button class="add-btn">+</button>
                                    <input class="cart_quantity_input" type="text" name="quantity" value="1" autocomplete="off" size="2">
                                    <button class="minus-btn">-</button>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="cart_total">
                                <p class="cart_total_price">$59</p>
                            </td>
                            <td class="cart_delete">
                                <!-- <a class="cart_quantity_delete" href=""><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a> -->
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section> <!--/#cart_items-->

    <section id="do_action">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- <div class="col-sm-6">

                </div> -->
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="total_area">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Cart Sub Total <span>$59</span></li>
                            <li>Eco Tax <span>$2</span></li>
                            <li>Shipping Cost <span>Free</span></li>
                            <li>Total <span>$61</span></li>
                        </ul>
                        <a class="btn btn-default update" href="{{url('cart')}}">Update</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-default check_out" href="{{url('checkout')}}">Check Out</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section><!--/#do_action-->
@endsection
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you included the javascript file? It seems that you only included the .css file.

Comment: I embed js code on this file, but I tried to use external js file too. I include .js file by this line: <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('public/js/cart.js') }}"></script>

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" {{asset('public/css/cart.css')}}"> should be inside head tag. isn't it.

Comment: @RuồiTrâu, in the one you posted here, you didn't include the .js file. Can you include it and check if it works? Also, put all your includes inside the <head> tag.

Comment: .css file doesn't have to put on head tag, I have tested it. And I meaned I test inlcude .js file before, it didn't work.

Comment: It still doesn't work. :(

Comment: @RuồiTrâu, are you using jQuery library? If you do, then include the file also.

Comment: I included, if you mean these lines:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('public/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js')}}"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('public/js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js')}}"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('public/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>`

Comment: @RuồiTrâu, You did wrong on your include it should be: "<script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL::asset('/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js')}}">"

Comment: still not work bro :(

Comment: @RuồiTrâu, I don't seem to see the "td.cart_delete" on any buttons you have.

Comment: Can you confirm that Jquery itself is actually working at all? Try loading jquery with a CDN if it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you are jQuery is working.

Here it is,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" {{asset('public/css/cart.css')}}">
@extends('layouts.layout')
@section('content')
<section id="cart_items">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="breadcrumbs">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li><a href="#">Trang chủ</a></li>
                <li class="active">Giỏ hàng</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <div class="table-responsive cart_info">
            <table class="table table-condensed">
                <thead>
                <tr class="cart_menu">
                    <td class="image">Mặt hàng</td>
                    <td class="description">Mô tả</td>
                    <td class="price">Giá</td>
                    <td class="quantity">Số lượng</td>
                    <td class="total">Thành tiền</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="cart_product">
                        <a href=""><img src="images/cart/one.png" alt=""></a>  <!-- Cái này chứa ảnh của sp -->
                    </td>
                    <td class="cart_description">
                        <h4><a href="">Tên sản phẩm</a></h4>     <!-- Tên sản phẩm -->
                        <p><a>Phan Thanh Tuyên</a></p>
                    </td>
                    <td class="cart_price">
                        <p>120.000 VNĐ</p>       <!--  Giá -->
                    </td>
                    <td class="cart_quantity"> <!--  Số lượng -->
                        <div class="cart_quantity_button">
                            <!-- <a class="cart_quantity_up" href=""> + </a> -->
                            <button class="add-btn">+</button>
                            <input class="cart_quantity_input" type="text" name="quantity" value="1" autocomplete="off" size="2" id="so_luong">          <!-- Đây cần thay đổi số lượng sản phẩm mua theo csdl -->
                            <!-- <a class="cart_quantity_down" href=""> - </a> -->
                            <button class="minus-btn">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="cart_total">
                        <p class="cart_total_price">$59</p>
                    </td>
                    <td class="cart_delete">
                        <!-- <a class="cart_quantity_delete" href=""><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a> Đây là nút delete một sản phẩm trong giỏ hàng. Chưa biết nên để <button> hay <a>. Cái này tùy cách xử lý của ô -->
                        <button class="quantity_delete" id="c_delete"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="cart_product">
                        <a href=""><img src="images/cart/two.png" alt=""></a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="cart_description">
                        <h4><a href="">Colorblock Scuba</a></h4>
                        <p>Web ID: 1089772</p>
                    </td>
                    <td class="cart_price">
                        <p>$59</p>
                    </td>
                    <td class="cart_quantity">
                        <div class="cart_quantity_button">
                            <button class="add-btn">+</button>
                            <input class="cart_quantity_input" type="text" name="quantity" value="1" autocomplete="off" size="2">
                            <button class="minus-btn">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="cart_total">
                        <p class="cart_total_price">$59</p>
                    </td>
                    <td class="cart_delete">
                        <!-- <a class="cart_quantity_delete" href=""><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a> -->
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="cart_product">
                        <a href=""><img src="images/cart/three.png" alt=""></a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="cart_description">
                        <h4><a href="">Colorblock Scuba</a></h4>
                        <p>Web ID: 1089772</p>
                    </td>
                    <td class="cart_price">
                        <p>$59</p>
                    </td>
                    <td class="cart_quantity">
                        <div class="cart_quantity_button">
                            <button class="add-btn">+</button>
                            <input class="cart_quantity_input" type="text" name="quantity" value="1" autocomplete="off" size="2">
                            <button class="minus-btn">-</button>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="cart_total">
                        <p class="cart_total_price">$59</p>
                    </td>
                    <td class="cart_delete">
                        <!-- <a class="cart_quantity_delete" href=""><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a> -->
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</section> <!--/#cart_items-->

<section id="do_action">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- <div class="col-sm-6">

            </div> -->
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="total_area">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Cart Sub Total <span>$59</span></li>
                        <li>Eco Tax <span>$2</span></li>
                        <li>Shipping Cost <span>Free</span></li>
                        <li>Total <span>$61</span></li>
                    </ul>
                    <a class="btn btn-default update" href="{{url('cart')}}">Update</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-default check_out" href="{{url('checkout')}}">Check Out</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section><!--/#do_action-->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("td.cart_delete").on("click", function () {
        alert("On click");
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
</script>

@endsection
```

Before click,

[image]

After click

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks for helping me. Can you tell me what I did wrong? Thanks you very much.

Comment: View source in browser. You can see the difference.